# Back Button in Python, I want to go back to the main window

Tags: python, button, tkinter, back

I have some problems with my code. I wanted to make a back button and I have an error when I display my window. My goal is to make a catalog in which the user can push some buttons and interact with the product. But when you push the button this error comes out.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/williamgranizo/.conda/envs/untitled/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/williamgranizo/.conda/envs/untitled/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tkmacosx/basewidget.py", line 255, in cmd
    self.unbind_class('button_command', '<ButtonRelease-1>')
  File "/Users/williamgranizo/.conda/envs/untitled/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tkmacosx/basewidget.py", line 496, in unbind_class
    bindtags = list(self.bindtags())
  File "/Users/williamgranizo/.conda/envs/untitled/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1192, in bindtags
    self.tk.call('bindtags', self._w))
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!toplevel2.!button6"
```

I don't know what is the main problem, but the main window seems to still work. My code is:

```
def m1():

ventana.withdraw
modelo_1 = Toplevel()
modelo_1.title("Rose&Frites Hoodie con Gorra")
modelo_1.geometry("700x700")
modelo_1.configure(bg='black')
fn_1 = PhotoImage(file='mblac.png')
lblfn = Label(modelo_1, image=fn_1).place(x=0, y=0)
foto_1 = PhotoImage(file='mg_1.png')
nom_1 = Label(modelo_1, text ='Rose&Frites Hoodie con Gorra', fg ='black',
              font=('Arial',20,'bold')).place(x=375,y=50)
myfoto_1 = Label(modelo_1, image=foto_1).place(x=50, y=30)
text_1 = Label(modelo_1, text= 'Promoción!! Hoodie de color negro\n con una estampa en forma de rosa. '
                               '\nTejido principal: 65%'
                    ' algodón, 35% poliester.\nTejido secundario: 97% algodón, 3% elástico.'
                    '\n Gorra color amarillo con \n estampa de papas fritas.\n 97% algodón, 3% elástico'
                    '\n100% Hecho en Ecuador', bg='white', fg='black', font=('Arial', 16)).place(x=375, y=100)
tallas=Label(modelo_1,text="Tallas!",font=("Arial",16,'bold'),bg='white',fg='black').place(x=500,y=300)
xl = Button(modelo_1, text="XL",font=("Arial",9,"bold"),width=60,bg='black',fg='white').place(x=385,y=350)
l = Button(modelo_1, text="L",font=("Arial",9,"bold"),width=60,bg='black',fg='white').place(x=445,y=350)
m = Button(modelo_1, text="M",font=("Arial",9,"bold"),width=60,bg='black',fg='white').place(x=505,y=350)
s = Button(modelo_1, text='S',font=("Arial",9,'bold'),width=60,bg='black',fg='white').place(x=565,y=350)
xs = Button(modelo_1, text='XS',font=("Arial",9,'bold'),width=60,bg="black",fg="white").place(x=625,y=350)
precio = Label(modelo_1, text="$35.00", font=('Arial',15, 'bold')).place(x=50, y= 485)
cuidados=PhotoImage(file='cuidados.png')
cuidados1=Label(modelo_1,image=cuidados).place(x=375,y=400)
cuidados2=Label(modelo_1,text="Cuidados",font=("Arial",15,'bold')).place(x=500,y=505)
iva = Label(modelo_1,text='El precio no contiene I.V.A.', font=('Arial',14,'bold')).place(x=500,y=660)
back = Button(modelo_1, text='BACK!', font=('verdana', 14, 'bold'), fg='red',
              command= modelo_1.destroy).place(x=0, y=0)
```

Comment: would you mind sharing at least some of the code to us as described in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ? If you share code with us read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example first

Answer (score 0):

*The error `_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name` triggers when you destroy any window with tkmacosx `Button`.* This issue has been fixed with the latest update to [tkmacosx (0.1.3)](https://pypi.org/project/tkmacosx/).

By updating the package with pip like so should fix the error.

```sh
pip install tkmacosx --upgrade
```

or

```sh
pip install tkmacosx==0.1.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your code:

```
back = Button(modelo_1, text='BACK!', font=('verdana', 14, 'bold'), fg='red',
              command= lambda:modelo_1.destroy).place(x=0, y=0)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64681676/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.